# MySQL not responding showing some message and holding in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

When I start MySQL in Ubuntu it was starting, but after using the

```
use database;
```

command, MySQL isn't reponding and showing message:

> Reading table information for completion of table and column names
>   You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that was the problem with dual boot or ram, it will work after sometime nearly takes 10-20 minutes to change the db then after it was working fine

Comment: The database must be huge to take that long. You might want to consider some optimisations or a hardware upgrade to add more RAM.